# 502 Bad gateway issue on API call from Postman or from app

Tags: php

I am using ionic app to fetch data from an API. An App calls an API with a POST method.
Following is the method in API that returns response.

```
public function sendResponse($returnVar, $status = 200){
        $content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
        //returns message equivalent to status code
        $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 '.$status.' '.$this->getStatusCodeMessage($status); 
        header($status_header);
        header('Content-type: '.$content_type); 
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        //LineA
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
        //LineB
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");

        if($status!==200){
            $returnVar["code"] = $status;
        }

        echo json_encode($returnVar);
        exit;
}
```

Where, `$returnVar` is the data returned by api method called. We don't have error anywhere else.

**Problem:**
I get 502 bad gateway error

I checked with `PostMan`. If i put `echo "Here" exit;` in `LineA`. It works well. But when i put it in `LineB`, then i get `502 Bad Gateway` error.
So clearly issue is in line `header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");` . But I am not sure what exactly is.
Can anybody throw some light on what I am missing? Thanks in advance

**Update**
Removing last three headers seem to work. Do I need last three headers in API response? I do have separate method to handle preflight requests.

**Update 2**
It sometimes work and sometimes does not. So with changes mentioned above, I still got 502 gateway error randomly with same api calls with same parameters.